# InfoPath validation for Alphanumeric Characters and period

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a Notes textbox in my InfoPath form which will contain multiple lines of text.

I wanted to add a validation so it can only contain Alphabets, Numbers and period .
No special characters like ! @ etc are allowed.

I tried

description does not pattern [A-Za-z]([ ]*[A-Za-z])* or

description does not pattern .*\d.* or

description does not pattern . or

But it throws validation error when I type "please help 123."

Please help!!!

Thanks

Comment: Anybody Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you use accept only exact same format as in your expressions, which means the input can only format as `A A` or `0` or `.`.

Try this one instead:

```
[A-Za-z0-9\.\s]*
```

[image]